# How do I execute some command only for module specified in <afile>?

Tags: vim

I want to execute `MyCommand` that needs access to `b:somevar` for buffer specified by `<afile>`.
Right now I'm doing something akin to

```
function F()
    let l:a = bufnr(expand("%"))
    let l:b = bufnr(expand("<afile>"))
    execute "bufdo call G(" . l:b . ")"
    execute "buffer " . a
endfunction

function G(d)
    let l:a = bufnr(expand("%"))
    if l:a == a:d
        execute 'MyCommand'
    endif
endfunction

autocmd BufDelete *.hs :call F()
```

So `F()` checks for every loaded buffer if it's the one in `<afile>`. It works but feels rather insane, there should be a better way.

Comment: Your autocmd is run on the `BufDelete` event on an haskell file. Why don't you simply check if the current file has that `b:somevar`?

Comment: When the `BufDelete` triggers, the current file may not actually be the one being deleted, but he needs the delete file shown in a window in order to execute `MyCommand` on it. Right?!

Comment: @IngoKarkat, @romaini Yep, there are many *.hs files and all have `b:somevar`, I only need to run `MyCommand` on the one being deleted.

Comment: Does `MyCommand` just need access to `b:somevar`? Then, it can use `getbufvar(expand('<abuf>'), 'somevar')`.

Comment: Nice question id, indeed.

Comment: The `BufDeletePre` event might suit your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `MyCommand` just need access to `b:somevar` (and maybe the buffer contents via `getbufline()`), then it can use `getbufvar(expand('<abuf>'), 'somevar')`.

---

If, on the other hand, it needs to execute commands on the buffer directly, you need to temporarily show the buffer in a window, like this:

```
function! ExecuteInVisibleBuffer( bufnr, command )
    let l:winnr = bufwinnr(a:bufnr)
    if l:winnr == -1
        " The buffer is hidden. Make it visible to execute the passed function.
        let l:originalWindowLayout = winrestcmd()
            execute 'noautocmd silent keepalt leftabove sbuffer' a:bufnr
        try
            execute a:command
        finally
            noautocmd silent close
            silent! execute l:originalWindowLayout
        endtry
    else
        " The buffer is visible in at least one window on this tab page.
        let l:currentWinNr = winnr()
        execute l:winnr . 'wincmd w'
        try
            execute a:command
        finally
            execute l:currentWinNr . 'wincmd w'
        endtry
    endif
endfunction
```

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to do everything I need with `getbufvar`